# java unable to read the XML file using FlatXmlDataSet

Tags: java, mysql, dbunit

I am trying to load an XML file to mySql using dbunit, my FlatXmlDataSet shows that

"Note: This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc could be found"

But getting AsserionFailedError:null

dbunit version -->2.4.9
mySql --> 5.2

```
public class DbUnitSampleTest extends TestCase {

public static final String TABLE_LOGIN ="login";
private FlatXmlDataSet loadedDataSet;

protected IDatabaseConnection getConnection() throws Exception
{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection jdbcConnection =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "root");

return new DatabaseConnection(jdbcConnection);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
protected IDataSet getDataSet() throws Exception
{               
        loadedDataSet = new FlatXmlDataSet(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("input.xml"));

        return loadedDataSet;
}   

public void testCheckLoginDataLoaded() throws Exception
{       
assertNotNull(loadedDataSet);
int rowCount = loadedDataSet.getTable(TABLE_LOGIN).getRowCount();
TestCase.assertEquals(2, rowCount);
}
}
```

Error:

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: null
at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:47)
at junit.framework.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:20)
at junit.framework.Assert.assertNotNull(Assert.java:214)
at junit.framework.Assert.assertNotNull(Assert.java:207)
at DbUnitSampleTest.testCheckLoginDataLoaded(DbUnitSampleTest.java:46)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here

```
loadedDataSet = new FlatXmlDataSet(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("input.xml"));
```

DBUnit has poor error messages.  The problem is that the resource loader can't find your input.xml file.  Try separating it out like this.

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("input.xml")
if(is != null)
   loadedDataSet = new FlatXmlDataSet(is);
else
   System.out.println("Can't find input.xml :(");
```

From there you should be able to track down why you can't find your input.xml.